# npm ERR! Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am trying to install some package, however, I don't know why I get such errors in the container:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.1.19-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm v3.8.3
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno -71
npm ERR! syscall symlink

npm ERR! EPROTO: protocol error, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/app/myapp/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR! https://github.com/npm/npm/issues

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR! /app/myapp/npm-debug.log
[Error] Failed to install npm dependencies. Exited with code 185.
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:latest

# System update
RUN apt-get -q -y update

RUN apt-get -q -y install npm
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
RUN npm install -g grunt-cli


RUN apt-get clean && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 8080

VOLUME ["/app"]
WORKDIR /app
```

Any can help?

Comment: Is this boot2docker on Windows? Looks like the filesystem where it is trying to create that symlink is is mounted from the host into the boot2docker VM and the underlying filesystem doesn't support symlinks. See this similar issue on npm github https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error your seeing suggests `npm` is failing to configure symlinks inside the Docker container. Use the `--no-bin-links` flag to avoid this:

```
npm install --no-bin-links
```

Comment: I'm not going to post a separate answer because this is basically the solution but just for clarity can you edit your answer to just have 'npm install --no-bin-links'? Installing grunt and gulp in the Dockerfile works fine but the later 'npm install' command (to instal dependencies for the package) will fail. See my comment on the question & the associated issue on github.